# TexLive 2017 installation "perl522.dll is missing" error

Tags: installing, texlive-2017

I download texlive 2017 from [this link](http://rsync.dante.ctan.org/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/) with rsync.
I run install-tl-advanced.bat. (Run as admin in windows)
but i got this error:

```
the program cant start because perl522.dll is missing from your computer.
try reinstalling the program to fix this problem
```

then i install perl. but The problem was not solved.
I go to this links:

ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/tlperl/bin/

and

rsync:     [ctan.asis.io/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/tlperl/bin/](http://ctan.asis.io/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/tlperl/bin/)

this file's Do not exist:

```
libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll  -  perl5.22.1.exe - perl522.dll
```

But in:

http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/tlperl/bin/?C=N;O=A
http://ctan.um.ac.ir/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/tlperl/bin/

```
(libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll  ,  perl5.22.1.exe , perl522.dll) are exist.
```

when i copt these file to mu texlive folder and then begin install,
i get this error:

```
install-tl" -gui perltk
"is_seven" is not exported by the TeXLive::TLWinGoo module
Can't continue after import errors at Z:\texlive\install-tl line 64.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

that 3 files was exist in texlive pretest. but, was deleted in "texlive 2017" first release (today). (but exist in install-tl.zip file)

what is solution?
thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you should install now. Not everything is already on all mirrors, I e.g. don't get updates for my pretest installation. So perhaps you didn't get everything. The needed perl is normally part of texlive:  In my pretest installation perl522.dll is in tlpkg/tlperl/bin.

Comment: If you have rsync-ed a TeX Live repository you should explicitly use that rsync-ed repository for the installation. I do not know the Windows version of the installer. But in the Linux version this can be done using option `-repository <path to local repository>`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer 
thanks. 
"In my pretest installation perl522.dll is in tlpkg/tlperl/bin"
yes. also for me. but in texlive 2017 was  deleted. 
but exist in install-tl.zip.
i test this mistake in several windows and clean windows's. and happened.

Comment: @Schweinebacke thanks. but, I do. In windows, installer chooses itself local repository automatically.

Comment: Why are you installing a new texlive if you already have the pretest? Anyway I think you should wait a day and then try again.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer
because pretest bugs is solved in texlive iso 2017. i am waiting...

Answer (score 1):

After today's update, the problem was solved.
texlive maintainer was added newer version of 3 file to `\texlive\tlpkg` folder.

```
(libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll  ,  perl5.24.1.exe , perl524.dll)
```

There may be other corrections ... .

thanks best wishes